# How to display the node Js sql query results as dropdown in HTML/EJS page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node Js.. Currently looking how to display the query values which is returned in Node Js should be displayed as dropdown value for select option..

```
\views\home.EJS

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Get Text Input Field Value in JavaScript</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="graphites.css">
</head>
<body>


<h1>Generate the Graph</h1>

   
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
            <% for(var i=0; i < dropdownVals.length; i++) { %>
               <option><%= dropdownVals[i] %></option>
            <% } %>
            </select>    
 

    
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="graphs.js"></script>
    <button class="button" type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.js

```
app.js

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var ejs = require('ejs');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var router = express.Router();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var sql = require("mssql");
    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'Februarysriram82$',
        server: '821Z33\\SQLEXPRESS',
        database: 'master',
        "options": {
            "encrypt": true,
            "enableArithAbort": true
        }
    };
    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select ACC_NBR from AUXI where CMPY_ID=00000339', function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        console.log(recordset)
        res.render("home", {dropdownVals:recordset});
        });
    });

    

});
var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "firstnodeapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "home.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express.js": "^1.0.0",
    "mssql": "^6.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Changan",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

when I give npm start or node app.js

In console, it is printing.. but in html it is empty value displaying,,

Can any one help on this? why it is not displaying node js..

Comment: Are you sure home.ejs is receiving the array? What you get with `<%= dropdownVals.length %>` ?

Comment: The record set is printing console log.. but i am doubt that received by home.ejs or not thats doubt.. because i am seeing empty values.. console output is..    { ACC_NBR: '510163111440' },
    { ACC_NBR: '510269979961' } do we need parse anything or anything missed here to return as array?

Comment: <h1>Generate the Graph for <%= dropdownVals.length %></h1>   this returns empty so i am guessiing it is not received

Answer (score 0):

You must register the router and put `listen` out.

```js
...
app.use('/', router);
var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Comment: output: still no luck.. the same output. C:\Projects\FirstNodeApp>npm start

> firstnodeapp@1.0.0 start C:\Projects\FirstNodeApp
> node app.js

Comment: Also, You need `var ejs = require('ejs');`.

Comment: added that as well similar behavior only comes

Answer (score 0):

when I change

```
  res.render("home", {dropdownVals:recordset});
```

to

```
 res.render("home", {dropdownVals:recordset.recordset});
```

it brings the value